# Animating translateY on a clipPath in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, svg

Why does the following clipPath animate in Chrome but not Firefox?

http://jsfiddle.net/H8S3k/67/

```
.graph {
  transform: translateY(150px);
  animation: 2s ease-out 0s normal none infinite popup;
}
@keyframes popup {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(50px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(50px);
  }
}
```

Comment: At some point CSS based svg animations stopped working in Mozilla and one can easily find quite a number of reports on the issue. I suggest you use [`<animate>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/animate) if your animation has to work in Mozilla.

Comment: No support for Internet Explorer though :/

Comment: If you need cross-browser svg animations, I suggest you start [here](https://css-tricks.com/svg-animation-on-css-transforms/). You're better off using javascript, at least for now.

Comment: Same problem: http://jsfiddle.net/H8S3k/71/ Works in Chrome, doesn't work in Firefox.

Comment: Edit: Got it working with the transform attribute, i.e. not the css property: http://jsfiddle.net/H8S3k/72/ . Woot!

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu your comment is not correct. CSS animations still work in FF. Perhaps you are getting confused with Chrome's decision to drop support for SMIL animations?

Comment: I was referring to [this bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1190881) and its duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SVG 1.1, only certain attributes were deemed to be stylable with CSS.  These particular set of attributes were called "properties".  You can see the list of designated properties here:

https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/propidx.html

`transform` is not one of those, so it cannot be styled with CSS.

However in SVG 2, which is not yet finalised, all SVG attributes will probably be made stylable.  Chrome has begun implementing this, however Firefox has not yet. That is why your example works in Chrome but not Firefox.